FPS drops and stuttering in the World Of Tanks game on Zorin OS
Since updated 1.24. the game produces performance issues on Linux.
I run the game with one of the latest versions of Proton via steam due to the fact that I've already had an wargaming account before the game released on steam store.
I searched through protondb for my issue and I found the WINE_CPU_TOPOLOGY launch argument workaround. But It didn't solve my problem, the game still drops my fps from 100+ to below 20 every 5 seconds.
I asked about on the wot discord server and the wot subreddit, they told me that my config is really outdated for it so it's of course the game stutters, but the problem is not related to my rig even tho I myself admit it's really old but I could play wot without any performance issues on medium settings around january this year.
Honestly, I really don't know what to do with this.
Is there any other fixes or workaround I can try to solve my problem?
I'm starting think it's dead end.
My config:

OS: Zorin OS 16.3 64bit; https://zorin.com/os/
Zorin OS 16.3 is based on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS compared to Zorin OS 16, which was based on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

CPU: Intel Core i5-6500 3.20 GHz x 4; Intel Ark

GPU: AMD Radeon R7 370

RAM: 24 GB (DDR3? / DDR4?)


Resources:

Minimum / Recommended system requirements list page
Official documentation on running WoT on Linux
Wine lists a Platinum result in testing 1.x (2018) version
Proprietary AMD graphics Linux drivers for Ubuntu 22.04 based OS

P.S.: Sorry if this place is not the right one for my issue, but I tried many subreddits to post my question, and none of them managed to make a proper answer for it.

that sounds like a regression of that game; not sure what anyone could do about it but the programmers of that game?

Please report this issue to the developer team, likely reachable from the page: https://na.wargaming.net/support/en/products/wot/help/   where I would choose Technical Issues -> Performance (FPS) and graphical issues, and continued to properly describe it. Good Luck!

I would personally report it, and adjusted my graphics settings to much lower, so that the developer team had time to isolate the issue, and you could still play nicely.

What version of Wine do you have installed? It may be important to update it from time to time if for games. wine --version should say wine-9.0

Finally, what AMD drivers do you use for your GPU card? I have only ever had experience with Nvidia, so I am naturally curious. :)

@VlastimilBurián I use my the built in drivers that comes with the kernel, also I use Mesa 24.1.1
For the compatibility layer I use proton 9-7

@VlastimilBurián about reporting the issue, providing a WGCheck report is necessary step of creating a ticket or I can skip it?

@VlastimilBurián my wine version is wine-6.0.3


I'd install the latest stable Wine version. 2. WGCheck report you should include if they want it. 3. I think you should install the proprietary drivers for your system.


@VlastimilBurián I've updated my wine version to 9.0, but the game still stutters. I couldn't even create a ticket to WG about since I must attach a WGCheck report file to submit, however the WGCheck tool which generates a report about the state of game files and other things stucks at 64.3% progress when I run the check procedure. And about installing AMD proprietary drivers, I heard from many linux users, that's unnecessary because the built-in drivers work more efficiently than the proprietary ones. So I think the only option is updating the kernel I guess

Who told you the official driver is unnecessary? Look, I use Nvidia (GPU card + proprietary driver) and the Nouveau driver is a total bull****, and I believe this will be the same for AMD...
